# How can I set and get the value of an input component using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, input, vue.js, v-model

I'm trying to set an initial value to some input components when created and then, after clicking a button, get those values if they are changed.

This works fine to set the initial values:

```
<template>
  <div class="editUserInfo">
    <input type="text" id="acName">
    <input type="text" id="acUsername">
    <input type="text" id="acEmail">
    <button v-on:click.prevent="updateInfo">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  data(){
    return{
      tokenExists: false,
      userCookie: {
        id: '',
        secret: '',
        expire_at: ''
      },
      newUserInfo: {
        nuName: '',
        nuUsername: '',
        nuEmail: '',
      },
      actualUserInfo: {
        acName: '',
        acUsername: '',
        acEmail: '',
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkToken(){
      if (this.$cookie.get('secret') == null){
        this.tokenExists = false;
      }else{
        this.tokenExists = true;
        var userInfo = JSON.parse(this.$cookie.get('secret'));
        this.id = userInfo.user_id;
        this.secret = userInfo.secret;
        this.expire_at = userInfo.expire_at;

        this.acName = userInfo.name;
        this.acUsername = userInfo.username;
        this.acEmail = userInfo.email;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    document.getElementById("acName").value = this.acName;
    document.getElementById("acUsername").value = this.acUsername;
    document.getElementById("acEmail").value = this.acEmail;
  }
  ...
</script>
```

However I need the v-model property in the input components to get those values when I click the button. When I add the v-model property the values are initialized properly but when I test the components by changing the values of one of them, the other input components are cleared.

This is not working:

```
<template>
  <div class="editUserInfo">
    <input type="text" id="acName" v-model="newUserInfo.nuName">
    <input type="text" id="acUsername" v-model="newUserInfo.nuUsername">
    <input type="text" id="acEmail" v-model="newUserInfo.nuEmail">
    <button v-on:click.prevent="updateInfo">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Thought that was a matter of losing the variables but I tested printing them in console and they are not changing or being undefined.

Comment: can you update your script part data binding

Comment: Done. There is the script code where I assing the values.

Comment: where is the newUserInfo that you binded in v-model in script part where you declared it

Comment: Done. Now that made me think that it's because the binding variables have an undefined  value. I've just modify one of them with an static value and it worked, the input didn't cleared. Now the question is how can I set the values to the variables in the data section so that they don't stay undefined?

Comment: no need to use `document.getElementById` we can bind using data section to v-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use document.getElementById we can bind using data section to v-model

```
<template>
  <div class="editUserInfo">
    <input type="text" id="acName" v-model="newUserInfo.nuName">
    <input type="text" id="acUsername" v-model="newUserInfo.nuUsername">
    <input type="text" id="acEmail" v-model="newUserInfo.nuEmail">
    <button v-on:click.prevent="updateInfo">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

In your script part

```
<script>
  data(){
    return{
      tokenExists: false,
      userCookie: {
        id: '',
        secret: '',
        expire_at: ''
      },
      newUserInfo: {
        nuName: '',
        nuUsername: '',
        nuEmail: '',
      },
      actualUserInfo: {
        acName: '',
        acUsername: '',
        acEmail: '',
      }
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.newUserInfo.nuName = 'somevalue'
    this.newUserInfo.nuUsername = 'somevalue
    this.newUserInfo.acEmail = 'somevalue'
  }
```

In 'somevalue' give what ever value you like and in method checkToken() also use it like mounted()

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much!